# Repeated-measures ANOVA - Where is the difference?

Tags: anova, repeated-measures

If I conduct a repeated-measures ANOVA and the p-value is significant (i.e., the means are NOT the same at all time points), what subsequent test would I conduct to determine where the difference(s) is?

Scenario:
2 independent variables: Group (i.e., treatment and control) and time (i.e., time points 1-3).

Comment: The terminology 'repeated measures' has been much abused--to the point that is almost meaningless. Please say how many factors you have, how many levels for each factor, write the ANOVA model. // If you are doing multiple paired comparisons among levels of a significant factor, then you need to use some method of avoiding 'false discovery' by doing repeated tests on the same data.

Comment: Estimating the difference in means does not require a test.  What would be the matter with subtracting one mean from the other?